# Refactor multiple times repeating code inside JS Classes into a single source

Tags: javascript, class, oop, types, refactoring

Im trying to merge multiple codes from multiple files into one. All have different js classes but all the same slick slider settings inside. I mean the part `initSlider() {...});` Any idea how to merge them into one?

```
    // Code inside File one
    window.$ = window.jQuery = $ = jQuery;

    class BRPScarousel{
      constructor() {
          this.els = $('.msbrps');
          this.slidesToShow = maxbrp_data.slides_to_show;
          this.initSlider();
      }
      initSlider() {
        $('.new_products').css("visibility","visible");
        this.els.not('.slick-initialized').slick({ 
        // always the same
        });
      }
    }
    var sc = new BRPScarousel();
    

    // Code inside File two
    window.$ = window.jQuery = $ = jQuery;  

    class XCPScarousel{
      constructor() {
          this.els = $('.msxcps');
          this.slidesToShow = maxcrp_data.slides_to_show;
          this.initSlider();
      }
      initSlider() {
        $('.bestr_products').css("visibility","visible");
        this.els.not('.slick-initialized').slick({ 
        // always the same
        });
      }
    }
    var sc = new XCPScarousel();
```

Comment: It is not clear from your example, what code is in what files. Also are they being loaded by the same page? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited the question to make it clear i hope. @Twisty

Comment: For the OP's use case one needs exactly a single (but of cause generic enough implemented) `ProductsCarousel`. At instantiation time one, in addition to the slideshow specific data object (e.g. `maxbrp_data` or `maxcrp_data `, etc.), has to pass both root node selectors one for `this.els` (e.g. `'.msbrps'` or `'.msbrps'`, etc.) and another one for `initSlider` (e.g. `'.new_products'` or `'.bestr_products'`, etc.). Of cause there needs to be an initialization task, which e.g. at *DOMContentLoaded* time takes care of whatever need to be initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment on @Zulfe's answer...

> *"For the OP's use case one needs exactly a single (but of cause generic enough implemented) `ProductCarousel`. At instantiation time one, in addition to the slideshow specific data object (e.g. `maxbrp_data`  or `maxcrp_data`, etc.), has to pass both root node selectors one for `this.els` (e.g. `'.msbrps'` or `'.msxcps'`, etc.) and another one for `initSlider` (e.g. `'.new_products'` or `'.bestr_products'`, etc.). Of cause there needs to be an initialization task, which e.g. at DOMContentLoaded time takes care of whatever needs to be initialized."*

```
// e.g. file ... src/utils/ProductCarousel.js

class ProductCarousel {
  constructor(data, elementsSelector, sliderSelector) {
    
    this.els = $(elementsSelector);
    this.slidesToShow = data.slides_to_show;
    this.sliderSelector = sliderSelector
    
    this.initSlider();
  }
  initSlider() {
    $(this.sliderSelector).css("visibility", "visible");
    this.els.not('.slick-initialized').slick({ 
      // always the same
    });
  }
}
export default ProductCarousel;

// end of file.
```

---

```
// e.g. file ... src/main.js

import ProductCarousel from 'src/utils/ProductCarousel.js'

$(document).ready(() => {
  
  const brpsCarousel =
    new ProductCarousel(maxbrp_data, '.msbrps', '.new_products');
  const xcpsCarousel =
    new ProductCarousel(maxcrp_data, '.msxcps', '.bestr_products');
});

// end of file.
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Classes_in_JavaScript#inheritance) for this.

```js
class SimpleCarousel {
    constructor(className, data) {
        this.els = $('.' + className);
        this.slidesToShow = data.slides_to_show;
        this.initSlider();
    }

    initSlider() {
        $('.bestr_products').css("visibility", "visible");
        this.els.not('.slick-initialized').slick({
            // always the same
        });
    }
}

class BRPScarousel extends SimpleCarousel {
    constructor() {
        super('msbrps', maxbrp_data);
    }
}

class XCPScarousel extends SimpleCarousel {
    constructor() {
        super('msxcps', maxcrp_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: nope ... for the OP's use case one needs exactly a single (but of cause generic enough implemented) `ProductsCarousel`. At instantiation time one, in addition to the slideshow specific data object (e.g. `maxbrp_data` or `maxcrp_data `, etc.), one has to pass both root node selectors one for `this.els` (e.g. `'.msbrps'` or `'.msbrps'`, etc.) and another one for `initSlider` (e.g. `'.new_products'` or `'.bestr_products'`, etc.)

Comment: Good catch on the additional parameters, but what if OP wants to discern the type of the carousel instance? A discriminator would need to be added to each instance. Where would these discriminators be defined? How would they be maintained? With inheritance OP can use `instanceof` as a means of discrimination. The classes exist as keywords and can easily be jumped to and investigated as opposed to free string discriminators that you just have to know.

Comment: Moreover inheritance gives OP the freedom to override the behavior of `initSlider()` per carousel type. A single parameterized class instance would not offer such freedom, at least not without more parameters and very generic code.

Comment: From the provided code one can not tell the future. And in case the OP needs such hypothetically stated behavior, sub-classing still can be done (and I was the last one to not follow this path). But here it's clear, the OP doesn't even get the base implementation right. Thus, the OP needs a single clean base class implementation and an initialization process which triggers the carousel instantiation.